# How do I rewrite “She has just bought a magazine” using “yet”?

Tags: word-usage, exam-questions

Rewrite the following sentence using the word in brackets.

> She has just bought a magazine. (yet)

My attempt (from a comment):

> She has yet just bought a magazine.

Comment: It's impossible since "yet" is attached to negative sentence.(in this case)

Comment: I cannot think of a way to write that sentence using *yet*.  It means "until now" or "still", so how could it be used to refer to a specific event that has happened?  Is this from a book or a homework assignment, or just a question that you have?

Comment: You are doing this wrong.  Don't start with a word and wonder how to express a meaning using that word.  Start with a meaning, and pick the best words.  In your case the best words are "She has just bought a magazine".

Comment: If "yet" means "however", you could say "Yet she has just bought a magazine".  But if "yet" means "up to now" then, as others have said, it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @JamesK This is a test/exam question. No point telling OP that it's not the right question!

Comment: Your book is old-fashioned. The answer I believe they want is "She has only yet bought a magazine". It's archaic and of no use to any learner  who wants to be able to speak English to modern humans.

Comment: While rjpond gave much the comment I would have, I don't think this question has a good answer. There is no way to use "yet" without substantially changing the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. How do you know it is a test question?  The OP doesn't say that. If it is a test question the correct answer is "do your best" and "ask your teacher". Then if you don't understand the answer, come back here.

Comment: @JamesK It’s a standard sentence transformation using a fixed keyword, as used throughout the Cambridge suite of exams and their many derivatives. Not the kind of q a user comes up with for their own amusement! Didn’t mean a teacher set test!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I take it that your *She has only yet bought a magazine* is in the sense that we'd more naturally express today as ***So far** she has only bought a magazine* (she hasn't taken things any further - for example, she hasn't yet ***read*** the magazine, or taken out a subscription, or whatever).

Comment: @FumbleFingers More like this: [“It is most certainly doing injustice to an Act which has only yet begun to be carried out in its full vigour , and the benefits and blessings of which are only yet begun to be felt : — to agitate the public mind about alterations which might not be ...”](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gx0FAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA782&dq=%22only+yet%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj96Zftx_buAhXKYMAKHZAHDfY4ChDoATADegQICBAD#v=onepage&q=%22only%20yet%22&f=false)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: oic. Looks like you could reasonably substitute ***just recently*** for ***yet*** there. Which presumably implies OP could just change ***just*** to ***yet*** and get top marks! "Indian English" sometimes hangs on to usages that have become obsolete for mainstream Anglophones, but it wouldn't be wise for ELL to encourage this particular usage among learners in general. I'm sure most people would reject it out of hand today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, couldn’t agree more, as I point out in my comment, I hope!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a fairly simple grammar exercise to check if you know where/how *yet* is commonly used. Both *just* (=very recently) and *yet* (=until now) are time expressions. You are supposed to substitute one for another, slightly rearrange words to form a question or a negative sentence because it's where the adverb is normally used.

> She hasn't bought a magazine yet.

> Has she bought a magazine yet?

Comment: You can't rewrite a sentence as an answer for a grammar exercise/exam by negating the meaning of the sentence!!!

Comment: When you are an English learner, you will come across many of those unsophisticated exercises where the meaning is often neglected...

Comment: For me, "rewrite" means write a sentence with the same or very close meaning to the one given. These "rewrites" reverse the meaning given.